# How to find an element intersect in other array

Tags: arrays, go, intersection

I have an array like:

```
a:= [1,2,3,4,5]
b:= [5,6,7,8,9]
```

How to know array b have contain element in array a without using foreach?

Comment: I just want find an utility function like array_intersect for golang php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: There is no build-in method for doing it, but there is a library that provides `set.intersect`: https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set. However, if you look at the implementation, you will see that there is a for loop running under the hood.

Comment: in all likelyhood the php utility function uses a foreach loop in itself, if you do it often, write the function urself

Answer (score 3):

> How to know array b have contain element in array a without using foreach?

You can't. And you should not try as this is pointless restriction.

Comment: You _could_.  You could use recursion, or some other convoluted method to not use a for loop. But outside of code golfing, you're right, the exercise is pointless.

Comment: I just want find an utility function like array_intersect  for golang
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: There is no such utility function.

Comment: @NguyễnDũng PHP comes with a big bag of utility functions (many of which are of doubtful value). Go doesn't, and you're expected to either do that yourself or use some third-party package/library for it.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are sorted (as they appear to be in your question) there is an algorithm that works better than going through each element.

Pick the first element of `a`, call it `x`.
Binary search `b` for the first element equal or greater than `x`. If they are equal, you found an element that is contained in both arrays, if not, make that your new `x`. Now search `a` for `x` in the same way. Repeat until you run out of elements in one of the arrays.

This can be trivially extended to an arbitrary number of arrays (in fact, it's easier to write with an arbitrary number of arrays).

Here's a quick and dirty implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func inter(arrs ...[]int) []int {
    res := []int{}
    x := arrs[0][0]
    i := 1
    for {
        off := sort.SearchInts(arrs[i], x)
        if off == len(arrs[i]) {
            // we emptied one slice, we're done.
            break
        }
        if arrs[i][off] == x {
            i++
            if i == len(arrs) {
                // x was in all the slices
                res = append(res, x)
                x++ // search for the next possible x.
                i = 0
            }
        } else {
            x = arrs[i][off]
            i = 0 // This can be done a bit more optimally.
        }
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
    b := []int{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    fmt.Println(inter(a, b))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    set "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
)

func array_intersect(a, b []interface{}) []interface{} {
    return set.NewSetFromSlice(a).Intersect(set.NewSetFromSlice(b)).ToSlice()
}
func main() {
    a := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
    b := []interface{}{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    println(array_intersect(a, b))
}
```

Comment: By using set.Intersect: github.com/deckarep/golang-set , the code is really simple.

Comment: I did not down vote, but at least 2 issues should be pointed out. 1) This solution is using a loop under the hood, 2) `array_intersect` normally keeps track of non-unique values, intersect of `[1,1,2,3]` and `[3,5,1,1]` should be `[1,1,3]`, while your solution will give `[1,3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func array_intersect(a, b []int) []int {
    ret := []int{}

    lenA := len(a)
    lenB := len(b)
    if lenA == 0 || lenB == 0 {
        return ret
    }
    sort.Ints(a)
    sort.Ints(b)
    var i, j int
    for {
        a = a[i:]
        if i = sort.SearchInts(a, b[j]); i >= len(a) {
            break
        }
        if a[i] == b[j] {
            ret = append(ret, a[i])
        }
        if j++; j >= lenB {
            break
        }
    }

    return ret
}
func main() {
    a := []int{5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
    b := []int{1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Printf("a=%v, b=%v", a, b)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", array_intersect(a, b))
    fmt.Printf("a=%v, b=%v", a, b)
}
```